# Convert every two values of an associative array into key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to convert an associative array into a new associative array where the original keys are ignored and every two consecutive values become new key-value pairs.

Input:

```
Array
(
    [SELECT0] => 'orange'
    [INPUT0] => '100'
    [SELECT1] => 'bannana'
    [INPUT1] => '200'
    [SELECT2] => 'apple'
    [INPUT2] => '300'
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [orange] => '100'
    [bannana] => '200'
    [apple] => '300'
)
```

Comment: Have you done anything yet to solve this? Can we see the code and where it fails?

Comment: I'm still trying, nothing even starts to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way combining three PHP array functions:

```
$result = array_combine(...array_map(null, ...array_chunk($array, 2)));
```

`array_chunk` gives you

```
[
    ['orange', '100'],
    ['banana', '200'],
    ['apple', '300']
];
```

`array_map` converts that to:

```
[
    ['orange', 'banana', 'apple'],
    ['100', '200', '300'],
];
```

Which can feed directly into `array_column`.

Comment: I don't think i fully understand your answer. i was trying to use that first short code and i am getting the right format, but for some reason it doesn't return all values, only some, and a weird order...

Comment: My real array is `array(12) {
  ["SELECT0"]=>
  string(3) "000"
  ["INPUT0"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["SELECT1"]=>
  string(3) "000"
  ["INPUT1"]=>
  string(3) "150"
  ["SELECT2"]=>
  string(4) "5260"
  ["INPUT2"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["SELECT3"]=>
  string(4) "5261"
  ["INPUT3"]=>
  string(3) "300"
  ["SELECT4"]=>
  string(3) "000"
  ["INPUT4"]=>
  string(3) "400"
  ["SELECT5"]=>
  string(4) "5262"
  ["INPUT5"]=>
  string(3) "500"
}
`

Comment: What i get with your code is: `array(4) {
  ["000"]=>
  string(3) "400"
  [5260]=>
  string(3) "200"
  [5261]=>
  string(3) "300"
  [5262]=>
  string(3) "500"
}
`

Comment: Yes, that's because a PHP array can't have duplicate keys, so you can't really get the structure you're going for from that input array without losing data.

Comment: Since you can't have multiple '000' keys, you just end up with whatever the last value is. You're going to have the same problem with any of the other answers, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, is loop over all you array values and then take every odd one as key and the next index as value.

```
$arr = [
    'SELECT0' => 'orange',
    'INPUT0' => '100',
    'SELECT1' => 'bannana',
    'INPUT1' => '200',
    'SELECT2' => 'apple',
    'INPUT2' => '300'
];

$arr = array_values($arr);
$newData = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $newData[$arr[$i]] = $arr[++$i];
}
```

Now `$newData` contains this:

```
Array
(
    [orange] => 100
    [bannana] => 200
    [apple] => 300
)
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming the format will never change ...

```
$new=array();//start a new array
$count=count($array)/2; //get the number of items to loop through


for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { //loop

$k='SELECT'.$i; //key
$v='INPUT'.$i; //value

$new[$array[$k]]=$array[$v]; //create new array

}

print_r($new); //display
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the uselss original keys from the input array with `array_values()`
2. Group the data into 2-element subarrays
3. Iterate the pairs and use "array destructuring" to temporarily declare the `$newKey` and then push the related value into the result array using `$newKey`.  The foreach's body is not required.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BOVYL))

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_chunk(array_values($arr), 2) as [$newKey, $result[$newKey]]);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'orange' => '100',
  'bannana' => '200',
  'apple' => '300',
)
```

Comment: +1 for using "disembodied foreach", hadn't ever thought it works without a body. Provides an interesting alternative for cases where `array_map` is basically what you want but you need keys, and `array_walk` feels clunky.

Comment: This is my latest epiphany while toying with array destructuring: [While destructuring an array, can the same element value be accessed more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807960/2943403).  I was very surprise to discover that that coding attempt actually worked.